# Jquery .animate() doesn't work second time i trigger it

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I am making a carousel of several objects. It is supposed to spin the carousel, so the next object is in focus, when I click the next/previous buttons. The first time I click one of the buttons, it slowly animates the spin, but with the next clicks it just changes object without animation for some reason. And it should animate everytime i click, but it does it only the first time after each page reload.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sxybreak/jouevx28/1/

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var angle;
    var i = 0;

    $("#previous").on('click', function() {

        i+=1;

        $("#carousel").animate({borderSpacing: 40}, {
            duration: 'slow', 
            step: function(now, fx) {

                $(this).css({
               'transform': 'rotateY(' + (i*now) + 'deg)',
               '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + (i*now) + 'deg)',
               '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + (i*now) + 'deg)',
               '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + (i*now) + 'deg)' });
        }
     });
  });


  $("#next").click(function() {

    i-=1;

    $("#carousel").animate({borderSpacing: 40}, {
      duration: 'slow',
      step: function(now, fx) {

        $(this).css({
            'transform': 'rotateY(' + (i*now) + 'deg)',
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + (i*now) + 'deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + (i*now) + 'deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + (i*now) + 'deg)' });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you are animating the setting of the border-spacing property.  Once the animation is complete the border-spacing is 40 and so there is nothing to animate to.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried to run it.but one reason that an animate is not working second time is because the natural queuing of animations.
just use .stop() after selector, as in

> $(this).stop()

Visit this link to know more
http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup

May be it will help other users coming to this page,just like me.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically using the step function to make your custom animation, right? So in the first transformation `borderSpacing` is `0`. This is animated to `40` where by calling your custom animation in each step.

However in the next click `borderSpacing` is still at `40`. So there is nothing to animate to, which is why it just add the `transform` without doing any animation.

A simple solution would be to reset the `borderSpacing` value to `"+40"` (previous) and `"-40"` (next) and use it in your animation.

Example :

```
$("#previous").on('click', function () {

    i += 1;

    $("#carousel").animate({
        borderSpacing: "+=40"
    }, {
        duration: 'slow',
        step: function (now, fx) {
            $(this).css({
                    'transform': 'rotateY(' + (now) + 'deg)',
                    '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(' + (now) + 'deg)',
                    '-moz-transform': 'rotateY(' + (now) + 'deg)',
                    '-ms-transform': 'rotateY(' + ( now) + 'deg)'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle showing working example : https://jsfiddle.net/jouevx28/3/

Comment: It's true that the animation isn't correct. As it is right now, it goes from    now = 0    to 40, 80, 120 and so on, and it is correct that I want it to go from current angle to    i*now    . I just have problems figuring out how to do that.

Comment: I fixed that. Check my edited answer. I'm updating the JSFiddle for you now

Comment: Ok. Your code had a couple of design problems. First use of `borderSpacing`. It won't go into negative. So I changed it to use `z-index` as the reference property for animating. Then for rotation, since we have a reference property stepping through `1` increment, I used `now` directly. Checkout the JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/jouevx28/3/ and see if this is what you wanted

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you, you're the best :)